# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output. While i install misp-modules

Tags: python

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6mujq2si/pytesseract/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6mujq2si/pytesseract/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-6mujq2si/pytesseract/pip-egg-info
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-6mujq2si/pytesseract/
Complete output (42 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/pip-install-6mujq2si/pytesseract/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 26, in 
from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-6mujq2si/pytesseract/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 121, in setup
    dist.parse_config_files()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 701, in parse_config_files
    parse_configuration(self, self.command_options,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 121, in parse_configuration
    meta.parse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 426, in parse
    section_parser_method(section_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 399, in parse_section
    self[name] = value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 184, in __setitem__
    value = parser(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 515, in _parse_version
    version = self._parse_attr(value, self.package_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 349, in _parse_attr
    module = import_module(module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/tmp/pip-install-6mujq2si/pytesseract/pytesseract/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .pytesseract import ALTONotSupported
  File "/tmp/pip-install-6mujq2si/pytesseract/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 28, in <module>
    import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

Plz try this :

- sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

if it doesn't work plz try this :

- sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev

Comment: Actualy libpq worked, i can not install REQUIREMENTS